# Cloud Run - Why did I (owner) suddenly lose access to my container registry?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-registry

Something must have changed over night and I can't access my container images anymore. The permissions look fine in AIM since I am the owner and only user.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think Google Cloud had a temporary malfunction, and all is well now. Weird.